# Need help with import problem on Aquia DEV desktop for Windows

Tags: 7

I am trying to import a DEV version of a site using the import function on Aquia Dev Desktop

I can successfully import the codebase and the sql dump file, but every time I go to the site, I get this error

**Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/xhprof/header.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in Unknown on line 0**

We have tried this on three different laptops, all using the same Windows 7 configuration. We get the same result every time. This leads me to believe that there is something wrong with the files that I was given to import

Does anybody have any insight into what might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the [XHProf](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) files at the specified path?

Comment: That is a good question. Thanks for the link, I will download and instal.  Here is my concern. We can create websites just fine, and we were also able to import them just fine. This problem didn't pop up until someone else we worked with started installing all sorts of plugins on the DEV server we are importing these files from without our knowledge. I was wondering if anybody knew if this might be a configuration issue with either our files or Aquia Dev Desktop- Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fixed this with a hammer.I hope we can find a more precise fix in the future.

These are the instructions I gave to our team

1. Go to root directory of your original localhost Drupal installation  (aka codebase)
2. Copy all the stand alone files –leaving the folders uncopied
3. Go to the root directory of your Drupal installation that you are trying to import (aka codebase)
4. Delete all the stand alone files in the codebase (leaving folders)
5. Paste in all the stand alone files from the localhost codebase

This should get things working again.

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out the line in settings.php that requires an include from the /var/www directory.

Make sure you open the correct settings.php - path will be sites/yourlocalsiteurl/settings.php.

For me the line to remove is line 260:

```
require('/var/www/site-php/myacquiacloudaccountname/myacquiacloudaccountname-settings.inc');
```

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work for me. There was nothing like that in the settings.php file. Interestingly, we had the same problem on a Mac. I copied the standalone files from the PC, and it worked. I have successfully imported other sites. This strengthens my belief that it had something to do with that site specific codebase. Thanks anyway, I hope your answer helps someone else.